# How to handle HTTP 510, 598 and 599 error codes in web.xml

Tags: servlets, web.xml

We use weblogic to deploy our application, the requirement is to handle all the server errors, 
in web.xml and have 500 through 510, 598 and 599. 
The specification of error codes - 510, 598 and 599 throws the following exception:

```
Exception:
<BEA-101024> Unsupported error status code for error-page in web.xml.
```

And the code in web.xml is as follows

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>510</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/main/http_error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Is there any other way to handle the 3 error codes(510, 598 and 599) or is it not required to be handled at all. 
Your suggestions on this is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: 510 Not Extended (RFC 2774)

Further extensions to the request are required for the server to fulfill it

Comment: 598 (Informal convention) network read timeout error

This status code is not specified in any RFCs, but is used by some HTTP proxies to signal a network read timeout behind the proxy to a client in front of the proxy.

Comment: 599 (Informal convention) network connect timeout error

This status code is not specified in any RFCs, but is used by some HTTP proxies to signal a network connect timeout behind the proxy to a client in front of the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is going to be returning those errors, presumably you're implementing some relevant feature - an RFC 2774 compliant extension that is returning a `510`, and a proxy that is returning `598` and `599`. Why not explicitly return the page content you want for those cases in the extension or proxy you are writing rather than using `web.xml`?